# jquery-css effect not working in .net page

Tags: jquery, hover

we are trying one image hover effect with jquery and css. It works fine in html page but same effect does not work in Asp.net (aspx) page. These both page are in one website project.

the demo from which I developed the page is here http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/zoomer/zoomer.html

here is the code of .aspx page.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <ul class="thumb">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Deepakbhai.jpg" alt="Deepakbhai and Kids" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Deepakbhai.jpg" alt="Deepakbhai and Kids" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Deepakbhai.jpg" alt="Deepakbhai and Kids" /></a></li>

    </ul>
```

This is placed inside the .net page and js files and css file is defined in header.

Comment: is there any error on nthe aspx? can you provide a link for that one?

Comment: when I run in IE 8 error is:                                        Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Tue, 7 Feb 2012 12:52:04 UTC


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 2
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:50254/zoomer.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 14
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:50254/WebForm1.aspx

Comment: @hetalgala check if jquery reference is added in the header of your page.
if added then try replacing jquery keyword with $ sign wherever you used jquery blocks hope it'll help

Comment: it uses $ sign in .aspx page.                                <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.thumb li').Zoomer({ speedView: 200, speedRemove: 400, altAnim: true, speedTitle: 400, debug: false });
});
</script>

Comment: on .net page it has inline javascript as follows
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.thumb li').Zoomer({ speedView: 200, speedRemove: 400, altAnim: true, speedTitle: 400, debug: false });
});
</script>
-- it shows error as follows
 $("ul.thumb li").Zoomer is not a function 
-- in firebug it shows following error

Answer (score 0):

```
@hetalgala Check that jquery reference is added in the header before Zoomer.js. because due to not finding the jquery reference in zoomer.js, it's giving the error 'jQuery Undefined'.

Script should be included in this format :

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zoomer.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.thumb li').Zoomer({speedView:200,speedRemove:400,altAnim:true,speedTitle:400,debug:false});
});

</script>
```